# iterate through an array in angular

Tags: angular

I'm new to Angular. I do not quite understand how *ngFor works in angular. Apperantly, you can only use it if you iterate through an array of objects and not only for an array. For my project, I need to go through an array that contains some IDs. Depending on that ID I will apply a badge. Somehow it only works for one and not for multiple.
I hope i explained it properly, ask for more information if it's not clear what I tried to explain.
[ids_pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txhSc.png)

Comment: Hi Lexy and welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you please add a starting point in code and what you have tried yourself?

Comment: Can you show and explain more details, Add a example data, code and/or image for visualization of your question, you will get downvoted

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Nevermind I actually solved the problem now - had to iterate through an array of objects

Answer (score 1):

```
@Component({/**/})
class MyComponent {
  public myArray: number[] = [11,12];
}
```

html:

```
<!-- ng-container for no html but with eaching -->
<ng-container *ngFor="let number of myArray"> 
  <div>{{number}}</div>
</ng-container>
```

or like this:

```
<!-- only one decorator with * per html block, for more when one - use ng-container -->
<div *ngFor="let number of myArray">{{number}}</div>
```